# Language code of a site collection

Tags: powershell, sharepoint-server, site, language

Is there a way to get the language code of a site collection using powershell?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [SPWeb.Language Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spweb.language%28v=office.14%29.aspx):

```
if ((Get-PSSnapin -Name Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) -eq $null)
{
    Add-PsSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell
}


$SiteUrl = "http://contoso.intranet.com/"
$site = Get-SPSite $SiteUrl
write-host $site.RootWeb.Language
$site.Dispose()
```